# Sending 1 email as invite to generated emails

Tags: privacy, email

I did some research regarding this question but all I could find was that email has to contain From, Subject forms, etc and unsubscribe links/button.

But how about if I want to send an invitation to my website (like dribble where you can register only with invites) to all of the university students (emails will be generated automatically) as a one time email, no future emails going to be sent. Do I need to follow some rules in order to make it all legal? Or is it sending as a normal email with the subject, from fields filled properly will do the job?

Comment: What jurisdiction, and what is the relationship between you and the university students ?

Comment: Well I was a student of that university and I have access to the emails etc. That's in UK. I was thinking sending invites to a various of colleges and unies